# having problems with this method in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe I'm too tired but I really can't understand why this thing is not working? I have the jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/ariret/19/edit

Thanks for your time!

```
<section class="">
    <p>Hello there, this is your flight info.</p>
    <div class="confirmation">
        <h3>Hawaiian Vacation</h3>
        <button class="btn">Flight details</button>
        <div class="ticket">
            <a href="#" class="view-boarding-pass">View Boarding Pass</a>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100" alt=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

jquery:

```
$('.confirmation').on('click', 'button', function() {
    console.log('works');
    $(this).find('.ticket').hide(); //why is  this not working?
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find()` is used for looking for child elements. The problem is `.ticket` is a sibling of `button`, so you need to use `next()`:

```
$('.confirmation').on('click', 'button', function() {
    $(this).next('.ticket').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the handler points to the button and `ticket` is not a decedent of button but it is the next sibling, so you need to use `.next()`

it should be

```
$('.confirmation').on('click', 'button', function(){
console.log('works');
           $(this).next('.ticket').hide(); //why is  this not working?

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use both of them:

```
 $(this).parent().find('.ticket').hide();
 $(this).next('.ticket').hide(); //why is  this not working?
```

You only can find for child of the current node.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I guess this is what you want

```
$('.btn').click(function(){

  $('.ticket').slideToggle();

  });
```

and the updated jsbin **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ariret/24/edit)**

Hope this helps. Thank you.